# What will happen in synthesis if a signal is only defined inside reset logic in always_ff?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, asic

Let's say I've following code:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk, negedge rst) begin
   if (~rst) begin
      bad_singal <= '0;
      good_signal <= '0;
   end else begin
      // do something
      // bad_signal is not used here or anywhere in design. 
      if (some condition)
         good_signal <= 1'b1;
   end
end
```

What will happen to bad_signal in synthesis? Will the synthesis tool optimize away the flop as it's not used anywhere in the design?

Answer (score 4):

If a signal or register doesn't drive anything, then yes -- any competent synthesis tool will trim it away, regardless of how it is set. Many synthesis tools will report a warning when this occurs.

Answer (score 1):

It should infer a latch technically.

Comment: But this is safe to waive. Isn't it?

Comment: @newbie yes indeed it is. Better not to use for such a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If it not used it will be optimized away. If it is used somewhere it will be tied to the ground since its value is always `0`.